# Creating virtual grouping set pl/sql select query

Tags: plsql, grouping

I have following query which returns me 6000 dates

SELECT to_date('03-Nov-2009') + (LEVEL - 1) datecol
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6000

1. 03/11/2009
2. 04/11/2009
   ...

I want to populate another column in the same query to show results as follows

1. 03/11/2009 1
2. 04/11/2009 1
3. 05/11/2009 1
4. 06/11/2009 1
5. 07/11/2009 2
6. 08/11/2009 2
7. 09/11/2009 2
8. 10/11/2009 2
9. 11/11/2009 3
10. 12/11/2009 3
11. 13/11/2009 3
12. 14/11/2009 3
    .
    .

not sure how I could achieve this grouping set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but does below query return what you wanted?

```
SELECT to_date('03-11-2009', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + (LEVEL - 1) datecol,
       trunc((level - 1) / 4) + 1 other_col
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;
```